# Simplify $\sin(2x -x)$

Tags: trigonometry

can $\sin(2x - x)$ be simplified to $\sin(x)$, or do I have to use a compound angle formula (with $\cos$ and $\sin$) to do subtraction here?

The context. I had this
$$ \frac{\sin(2x-x)}{\sin (x) \cos (x)} = \sec(x) $$

and wish to simplify it to

$$ \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} = \sec(x) $$

which would then allow me to prove

$$ \frac{1}{\cos(x)} = \sec(x). $$

If I'm not allowed to simplify $\sin(2x - x)$ to $\sin(x)$, then how would you prove

$$ \frac{\sin(2x-x)}{\sin (x) \cos (x)} = \sec(x) $$

**Update:** The original question asked me to "Prove the identity"

$$ \sec (x) = \frac{\sin (2x)}{ \sin (x)} - \frac{\cos (2x)}{\cos (x)} $$

I cross multiplied to get a common denominator

$$ \sec (x) = \frac{ \sin (2x) \cos (x) - \cos (2x) \sin (x)} {\sin (x)\cos (x)} $$

from there, the numerator on the right side really looked like the compound angle identity for $\sin(x - y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) -\cos(x)\sin(y)$ except that $y$ in this case was $x$ and $x$ would be $2x$, so I simplified to

$$ \frac{\sin (2x-x)}{\sin (x) \cos (x)} = \sec(x) $$

which brings me to the question, is $\sin(2x - x)$ the same as $\sin(x)$?

Comment: what is $2x-x = \ldots$?

Comment: I posted an update explaining where 2x -x comes from

Comment: @Michael I think Chester's comment was meant to be a hint rather than an actual question. The hint is: what is in general $2x -x$ equal to?

Comment: @RogelioMolina ok, thanks, but I thought simple subtracdtion and addition couldn't be done inside sine and cosine etc, hence the need for compound angle formulas? so it's ok to simplify to sinx? sorry for the newbie question

Comment: Yes, you can do it, your solution is completely valid.

Comment: The point of the compound angle formulas is that you _can_ do addition and subtraction inside the argument of a function. So for example if you know the sine and cosine of $\frac\pi3$, and you know the sine and cosine of $\frac\pi8$, then you can use an angle-sum formula to find $\sin\left(\frac{11}{24}\pi\right)$, because $\frac{11}{24}\pi = \frac\pi3 + \frac\pi8$ and therefore $\sin\left(\frac{11}{24}\pi\right) = \sin\left(\frac\pi3 + \frac\pi8\right)$.

Comment: @Michael You can carry out operations inside functions, so $\sin(2x-x) = \sin x$, or $\sqrt{10 - 7} = \sqrt{3}$, etc. What you *can't* do (in general) is carry out operations between functions, so, for example, there is no way to combine $\sqrt{10} - \sqrt7$. Trigonometric functions are a special case because there are nice identities for working with expressions like $\sin\alpha + \sin\beta$, but the point is that this latter expression is not equal to $\sin(\alpha + \beta)$.

Comment: $x\in R\implies 2x\in R$ because multiplication is closed with respect to the Reals. Similarly, $2x-x\in R$ because subtraction is also closed with respect to the Reals. Luckily, we can define $\sin$ so that its domain is the set of Real numbers.

They still teach the closure principle in high school don't they?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  you should simplify $\sin (2x-x)=\sin (x)$. I mean the first option is correct.